# Multithreading useful upto what extent?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrent-programming

- I have a task which can I divide into multiple independent subtasks and Each subtask can be run in a separate thread in Java.
- I want to understand what is the optimal number of threads after which increasing the number of threads will not lead to any performance gain.

Comment: Limited by number of processors

Comment: @blob: no, not in the general case. It is only true if the tasks are CPU bound. If they are mostly performing IO, then it's not limited by the number of processors.

Comment: @Bruno I agree, posted a informative link as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of factors here.  You are only limited by the number of processors/cores if your tasks are CPU bound.  If your tasks tend to be IO bound, then you will likely benefit from more threads than processors/cores. How many depends on how much time your tasks are spending waiting on IO, relative to how much time they spend doing actual compututations.

So, as usual, it depends on what you're doing.

For CPU bound processes, the number of running threads shouldn't need to exceed the number of cores.

In the end, you will need to try different configurations and see what works best.

Comment: +1: For some CPU intensive tasks the number of cores*2 turns out to be optimal. Usually its just the number of cores as you say, but if you benchmark your code you might find double is slightly better. Again it depends on what you are doing as for some tasks the optimal number is 1. ;)

Comment: Absolutely you should always measure when you change this kind of configuration.  Do you have a reference for the cores*2 assertion, Peter? I'd be interested to read about what sort of tasks might fall into that category.

Comment: It just a matter of trying all the options to find the best combination.  The core*2 comes from experience.